# Laravel: "force" query builder to return empty list

Tags: php, laravel

I have these routes:

```
Route::apiResource('payments', 'PaymentController', ['except' => ['store', 'destroy']]);

Route::get('users/{user}/payments', [
    'as' => 'users.payments',
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@index',
]);
```

And this controller:

```
class PaymentController
{
    public function index(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        // Initialize query builder
        $query = Payment::query();

        // If a user was provided, return all payments belonging to that user
        // if condition is satisfied
        if ($user) {
            if (condition) {
                $query = $customer->payments();
            } else {
                // Some code that causes no results
                $query->whereNull('id');   // <----- This hits the database
            }
        }

        return PaymentResource::collection($query->paginate(10));
    }
}
```

If you hit `/payments` it should return all payments made by all users.

If you hit `/users/id/payments` it should return all payments made by the user only if `condition` is true, otherwise it should return an empty list.

This code works, however `$query->whereNull('id');` is a workaround that actually hits the database.

Is there any way to avoid hitting the database and still return an empty list?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you just `return PaymentResource::collection(collect());`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to have a single return in the function, but is easier to follow the advice that @Chin Leung gave (thanks!)

```
class PaymentController
{
    public function index(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        // Initialize query builder
        $query = Payment::query();

        // If a user was provided, return all payments belonging to that user
        // if condition is satisfied
        if ($user) {
            if (condition) {
                $query = $customer->payments();
            } else {
                // Some code that causes no results
                return PaymentResource::collection(collect());
            }
        }
        // Other code here, for example a where statement
        // depending on what is passed in $request


        return PaymentResource::collection($query->paginate(10));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may avoid hitting the database and still return an empty list using 
initialized variable to empty collection or array

```
class PaymentController
{
    public function index(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        // Initialize query builder
        $query = Payment::query();

        // If a user was provided, return all payments belonging to that user
        // if condition is satisfied
        $return = collect();
        if ($user) {
            if (condition) {
                $return = $customer->payments()->paginate(10);
            } 
        }

        return PaymentResource::collection($return);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what about if I need to apply some filters (passed in the `$request`) to the query ? And, if no user is provided, the expected behavior is to return all payments of all users (and eventually apply some filters to them). The overall idea is: if a `$user` is provided consider only the payments of the `$user`, otherwise consider all payments